# Clicking on row in v-data-table with template rows

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

When I added template rows (so that they have special formatting based on condition):

```
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
    @click:row="clickedHandle"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="props">
      <tr v-if="props.item.name.includes('Fro')">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td v-for="itemx in myheaders">{{ toThousands(props.item[itemx]) }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-else>
        <td v-for="itemx in props.item">{{ itemx }}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

The function that is supposed to be called on row click `clickedHandle` does not fire up at all.  Why is that so?

Here is the example where you can check this behaviour:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-lro4w?file=/src/layout.vue

The table does not seem to react on row click at all.

```
clickedHandle(value) {
  console.log(value);
},
```

`clickedHandle` should log some value on row click.

Comment: i have just updated my answer

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the question, because in your answer there is no click mechanic at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize each cell individually as they do in the `v-data-table` row customization [docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#customizing-default-rows), not the whole row.  You can use a `v-for` to dynamically target the cell slots you want (in conjunction with your `myheaders` array):

```html
<template v-for="header in myheaders" v-slot:[`item.${header}`]="props">
  <template v-if="props.item.name.includes('Fro')">
    {{ toThousands(props.item[header]) }}
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    {{ props.item[header] }}
  </template>
</template>
```

You could avoid this slot and filter complexity by preparing your data ahead of time in a computed.

Here is an updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-nsqsx)

Comment: What if I have dynamic column names(except for the first column)?  Thats why I use this list `myheaders` so that I can pick the column names from it. Thats why cant manually choose `props.item.calories`

Comment: Thanks, Im not sure filters are the best use case, as this `scaleSelect` variable is changed in my app, outside the filter function and then based on the value i format the data. But with the filter the table seems to break: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-l160k?file=/src/layout.vue

Comment: You can use the method.  Just remember that preparing the data in a computed would be ideal

Comment: I agree, its more like it seemed to be more straightforward to just apply method on the values in the table instead of providing table with preformatted values, but ended up more complicated

Comment: Yeah.  And the template method could cause the app to become slow if it was larger because of the `includes` function having to search each item on every re-render

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      hide-actions
      class="elevation-1"
    >
     <template slot="items" slot-scope="myprops">
  <tr v-if="myprops.item.name.includes('Fro')">
 ...
  </tr>
  <tr v-else>
    <td v-for="itemx in props.item">{{ itemx }}</td>
  </tr>
</template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: But I need the template part for the conditional formatting of the table